# How to make Google Maps Javascript API calls periodically in background?

Tags: php, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, dom-events

I am creating a map with polygons fences(using Google Maps Javascript API) and want to periodically check if certain points(location of mobile devices) exist within those fences. I certainly have the location of mobile devices available periodically. But would like to know if it is possible to somehow make the API calls in the background and receive data without having to load/view the web page.. and also how the same could be implemented?

To add, what I want to precisely achieve is this:

The Google Maps Javascript API has a Geometry library that allows to make calls to a method `google.maps.geometry.poly.containsLocation(LatLng coordinate,Polygon polygon)`.

I have the both the  `coordinate` and `polygon` coordinate values stored in the database. But somehow I need to be able to periodically call this method on the API and make some changes to the devices being tracked which I am still stuck at. The periodic check needs to be implemented in C++ or would be glad to take in any recommendations.

I had a look at https://github.com/tparkin/Google-Maps-Point-in-Polygon to see if I can convert this logic and avoid making API calls but the library is still not being supported.Need to explore it further.
 Any help/guidance is appreciated.

Comment: Yes it is possible.

Comment: @geocodezip How can it be implemented in background?

Comment: Is there a reason why this question is downvoted?!

Comment: Can you provide a bit more detail on what API calls you're making that you'd like to move to the background?  I have a few ideas, but need more details.

Comment: @bamnet I have added some more details.. please let me know if I missed anything. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If you have a point and a polygon, you don't necessarily need to use the Google Maps API at all.  If you have code written in C++, it might be easier to use a library like the ones discussed in the [GIS section here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/147629/testing-if-a-geodesic-polygon-contains-a-point-c).

Doing this in the background using JavaScript would require [ServiceWorkers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Service_Worker_API) which I don't believe would work with the Google Maps JS API.

Comment: I will be going with the first approach instead! Thanks!